# SQL Server Integrated Security with ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, authentication, asp-classic

I'm working with getting a legacy app in line with current SQL Server security standards at my organization and would like the application to use Windows authentication when making SQL Server stored procedure calls from an ASP classic app runniing on a Windows Server 2008 web server. If it's too much trouble I can create a SQL Server account but would like to use integrated security. I'm looking for the best practice with this type of configuration. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? There are hundreds if not thousands of examples of doing this on this and every other corner of the internet.

Comment: I probably should have thought about this a little more before posting. My apologies. I understand how I can use Windows authentication. I am more interested in a secure approach which probably just comes down to getting a new AD account created and configuring both IIS and SQL Server to use it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

By ASP side it should be easy, it's a matter of connection string.
Try this one:

```
strConn="Driver={SQL Server}; Server=[YOUR HOST]; Database=[YOUR DB]; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

Before that, you have to properly configure IIS